# C++ - std::decay<T> and std::make_tuple<D> - cannot convert argument from 'D' to 'D &&'

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples

I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
void someFunction(){
   typedef std::decay<T>::type D;

   D val = GetValue<D>();
   std::tuple<D> t = std::make_tuple<D>(val);

   //... tuple is stored outside this scope in global variable
}
```

`GetValue<D>()` returns value from dictionary based on `typeid(D)`, it is working correctly and I return `MyData` to `D` - I tested it if I comment out the next problematic line, see the problem below.

If I compile this, for `T = const MyData &` I got this

```
 error C2664: 'std::tuple<MyData > std::make_tuple<D>(D &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'D' to 'D &&'
```

Why is this error produced and how to remove it? I want to store only non-ref values in my tuple, even if template T is refd'.

I can get it compile, by using `std::make_tuple<D>(std::forward<D>(val))`, but it calls my move ctor and I want to cal copy ctor, because `val` is destroyed at the end of method and so its internal data and move ctor just moved them, so they are gone.

Comment: I can see wanting to avoid accidently calling both a copy and move constructor, but your move constructor should be invaliding the original object to prevent this problem. If it cannot you likely should just remove it as nearly any use of a move constructor would break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never pass explicit template parameters to `make_tuple` and `make_pair`. Their power lies exactly in their ability to deduce types, as well as decaying them and unwrapping reference wrappers.

The following should work:

```
std::tuple<D> t = std::make_tuple(std::move(val)); // forward is superfluous here
```

or, better yet:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(GetValue<D>());
```

Comment: Also, replacing `std::tuple<D>` with `auto` may be a good idea.

Comment: @krzaq It compiles OK, but if I step the code line by line, I still end up in move ctor (`MyData::MyData(MyData&& other){}`)

Comment: @MartinPerry: As long as it is calling the copy constructor first calling the move constructor afterwards is fine (since you are just moving the copy). It should call the copy constructor when you store `GetValue<D>()` into `val`.

Comment: @Guvante `GetValue` calls copy ctor (create A), then tuple calls move ctor (create B).. but after that, copy (A) dtor is called and it takes the data in move (B) with it

Comment: @MartinPerry I think this is dependant on your compiler's ability to perform (N)RVO, and that, in turn, depends on the implementation of `GetValue`. What happens if you just write `std::tuple<D> t{GetValue<D>()};`

Comment: @krzaq It behaves the same.. I am using MSVC 2015